# Executing a method call with Java atomic variables

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

Suppose I have a code block like this

```
if (counter < 100) {
    synchronized (counter)
        if (counter < 100) {
            doSomething();
            counter.incrementAndGet();
        }
    }
}
```

where counter is an `AtomicLong`. How would I convert this block to not using the `synchronized` keyword anymore and still keeps its correctness? Or is it impossible?

Comment: Assuming counter **is** an AtomicLong, your code doesn't compile. You can't compare an object and an integer using the `<` operator.

Comment: What do you mean by "keep its correctness" - in what way is this code correct?

Comment: Since you have the 'doSomething' inside of the synchronized block, an AtomicLong isn't really a sufficient replacement. You could use the one of the `getAndUpdate` but it is a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on `doSomething` which you haven't shown. It may rely on being called from within a synchronized block, and may not even be parallelizable.

One substitution which I think is likely to be acceptable is

```
if (counter.getAndIncrement() < 100) {
    doSomething();
}
```

But suppose `doSomething` always throws an exception. In your code the counter can never be incremented, so the condition will always resolve to true. In the above example, it will be called the first 100 times, and even if they fail they will count as an iteration.

So in short, in order for us say if correctness is maintained then you need to define very specifically what it means for it to be correct.

If you don't know what it means for it to be correct then you are better off leaving it as it is.

Comment: While not the direct answer that I can copy and paste, I got an idea from your answer and it solved my problem. Thanks!